# Mars like world at a Venus like solar distance

Tags: weather

I'm putting together a homebrew adventure for a space horror game (using the Aliens RPG ruleset) and I was thinking about what a world with Mars like mass and lack of volcanic activity and ozone layer be like at a Venus like distance from the sun.   Would/could such a world still have the very thin Martian atmosphere?   Given such a thin atmosphere and a close sun would it be right to think there would be a great difference in night to day temperature, especially if the planet had an Earth-like period of rotation?  Would this drive a very stormy climate (of course the thin atmosphere might make this quite different to storms on Earth)?  What other features should there be on such a world?

Comment: Thanks I'll ask there, I'm new to StackExchnage

Comment: Hi Andrew. We're happy to help, but you've asked a lot of very large questions and Stack Exchange invites you to ask only one question. You might want to start with, "can a world like Mars is today exist in the orbit occupied by Venus?" Asking more than one question at a time is, in fact, a reason to close a question (see the explanation under "Needs More Focus").

Answer (score 12):

A Mars-like planet orbiting at a Venus-like distance would very likely be quickly stripped off most of its thin atmosphere by the solar wind and the lack of magnetic field, resulting in an even thinner one.

As a result, temperature differences between day and night could be quite extreme, somewhere in between what we have on Moon and Mercury: the thinner the atmosphere, the less buffering capacity it can offer.

I also think that, due to the very low mass involved in the atmosphere, its capability of storing energy would be low, and therefore the weather phenomena resulting from this stored energy wouldn't be particularly impressive.

Comment: Would have very high wind speed, blowing with insufficient strength to move even dust. Definitely a non-starter.

Answer (score 9):

> Would/could such a world still have the very thin Martian atmosphere?

It could. The trick is to balance out the timescales of things... as L.Dutch observed, the absence of a magnetosphere is bad news for atmospheres, but that's fine because you can set your adventure at the correct time period where any planetary magnetic field has reduced and the solar wind and radiation pressure has largely stripped the atmosphere away. This might involve a younger star and planet, but it can still be made to work.

> Given such a thin atmosphere and a close sun would it be right to think there would be a great difference in night to day temperature, especially if the planet had an Earth-like period of rotation?

There'll be a big difference, but it is hard to say what.

The [planetary equilibrium temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature) would be something like 318K. Mars has temperature variations of the order of 50K, but it is a long way from the Sun... our Moon, by comparison, has temperature variations of more like 200K from midnight to midday, but has a very long day.

A variation of ~100K coldest-to-hottest would put the ambient temperature at the boiling point of water at midday. That's a pretty hostile desert world right there, and it might be underestimating how hot things could get... the equator would likely get much hotter, for example.

> Would this drive a very stormy climate (of course the thin atmosphere might make this quite different to storms on Earth)?

I wonder if there would be enough energy to have near continuous dust storms. They'd spoil the view, but they might reduce the scorching daytime temperatures and provide a way to distribute heat-energy to the cold side.

Omnipresent ultrafine dust would play absolute havoc with any mechanical systems, and seals likely wouldn't be able to keep the stuff out. It'll end up everywhere, including in the lungs and bloodstream of anyone living there, because there's no practical way to keep it out if you're ever cycling airlocks or changing in to/out of a spacesuit. Better hope it isn't toxic (which it probably will be!).

> What other features should there be on such a world?

Too many to list. Such an open-ended request is far too broad, and effectively unanswerable on a site like this. Ask for something more specific.

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of sub questions here which I will try to address.

```
Would/could such a world still have the very thin Martian atmosphere?
```

It could, and this would result in significant temperature differences.

```
Would this drive a very stormy climate (of course the thin atmosphere might make this quite different to storms on Earth)?
```

I would not expect it to. On planets with thick atmospheres like Neptune and Jupiter we see long lasting storms, less so on thin atmosphere planets like Mars. Even though the temperature might be different there will be energy exchange, but it won't have enough mass to cause damage like an earth storm.  More like moving dust and clouds, but no tearing up trees.

```
What other features should there be on such a world?
```

If has a thing atmosphere and no magnetosphere I would expect it to be not only hot, but radioactive because of cosmic rays during the day, while brutally cold at night.  Also with so much electrical interference, without an earth like magnetosphere most electronics would be useless, during the day, without special magnetic shielding or Faraday caging.

If it has a thick atmosphere it would need the magnetosphere to protect it, but that is what would cause the intense storms.  If the atmosphere was thicker we could see this play out as storms build up much slower and take much longer to subside.  Think a hurricane that takes a week to get up to 7 mph winds, but the wind is almost as thick as water and makes it incredibly hard to travel safely.

Also it is worth mentioning that most planets closer to the sun have much longer days (Venus takes 118 earth days to rotate). You might want to provide explanation or at least mention that it is unusual for a planet to have such a short day so close to its star.

Comment: "planets closer to the sun have much longer day" - this is tidal locking. It's a process, and the closer something is to the body it orbits the faster it will happen. So the younger the planet, the more likely it is to not yet be tidally locked.